# Inform of or Inform about

Tags: prepositions

Which one  is more appropriate?( only the most appropriate is the right answer)

```
Who informed you about the matter ?
Who informed you of the matter?
```

which preposition is more proper than other to use after "inform" in the exam?

Answer (score 1):

*Inform* is used with both *of* and *about*. So they both are correct. Here are more examples taken from different dictionaries:

1. Why wasn't I informed **about** this earlier?
2. Walters was not properly informed **of** the reasons for her arrest.
3. It is with great sorrow that I inform you **of** the death of our director.
4. Companies publish annual reports to inform the public **about** the previous year's activities.
5. ...efforts to inform young people **about** the dangers of drugs.
6. We will immediately inform you **of** any changes to the programme.

**Note** that *of* sounds a bit more formal.